# Remove redirect to logs for a single command in bash

Tags: bash, logging, io-redirection

I tested everything from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions and a few others that do that redirect.

I got an interactive script that asks the user for input and at some point launches vi/nano for edit of a config file. That edit process throws a warning for vi, totally destroys nano and puts weird stuff into the log. Tested non working examples:

```
LOG_FILE=log.log
(
  echo "cool output"
  nano newfile.txt
  echo "back"
) |& tee $LOG_FILE
```

and

```
LOG_FILE=log.log
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$LOG_FILE 2>&1    

echo "cool output"
nano newfile.txt
echo "back"
```

Comment: In your first example, what's the expected content of `$LOG_FILE`?

Comment: `cool output` and `back` - that actually works without the nano part and is equivalent to redirecting > and 2> separately.

Comment: Both `vi` and `nano` are designed for interactive usage, using cursor control, expecting feedback from the screen. You will get more mileage if you can use batch editing tool (sed). Potentially, 'ex', the command line version of 'vi' may be better.

Comment: git itself is also opening I think nano by default? `ex` is a good tip I will see if that works. (I don't really care about the editor to open I jut need an editor for the user to open for simplicity)

Comment: According to the SO post you linked you need to run nano like this: `nano newfile.txt >&3 2>&4`. That means, just use the second variant in your question but change the way you run nano.